# Give write access to USB and Serial devices automatically

Tags: command-line, batch

I am working with some USB and Serial micro-controllers. Everytime I plug a device I have to do the following command to give it write access, and also my password:

```
sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Can I set my Ubuntu to automatically give write access to pluged in devices?

If not, how can I make a batch file that I can easily give the access to port I want for example if I run the following command it does the job:

```
giveaccess -usb0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add your userid to the dialout group. Suppose your userid is joeuser, then do:

```
sudo adduser joeuser dialout
```

and then log out and log back in again for this to take effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by configuring `udev` in `/etc/udev/rules.d`. There should be a `README` file right there for you to read first.

It should be pretty straightforward. More about this can be read for example here: ["Writing udev rules"](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html).

An example:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0123", SYSFS{idProduct}=="4567", ACTION=="add", GROUP="audio", MODE="0666"
```

would give an USB device of vendor id `0123` and product id `4567` the group `audio` and a file mode of `0666` when added to the system.

Answer (score 0):

working udev rule:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="03eb", ATTR{idProduct}=="2107",GROUP="dialout", MODE="0666"
```

idVendor and idProduct for Atmel AVR Dragon