# WANTED: User-friendly way to assign owner/permission when attaching a new serial devices (USB, BT, etc)

Tags: usb, permissions, bluetooth, udev

When attaching a serial device (e.g an arduino via USB or Bluetooth), the owner:group is set as root:dialout, e.g:

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Apr 15 18:08 /dev/ttyACM0
```

However, even when the regular user is part of the dialout group, it is necessary to change permissions on the device file (to 666).

This is only temporary until the device has been disconnected. A persistent solution is to modify the udev file. See e.g. this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219830/give-write-access-to-usb-and-serial-devices-automatically) and this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15570/configure-udev-to-change-permissions-on-usb-hid-device/557741#557741)

This can be confusing, not least when the Bluetooth system tool (blueDevil on KDE) can detect USB devices, but not connect to them.

It seems to me, that either the default behaviour should be to grant dialout users write access or at the least this should be part of the GUI system setting tools.

```
$id
uid=1000(soon) gid=1000(soon) groups=1000(soon),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),116(lpadmin),126(sambashare)
```

Comment: Group members *have* write permission. The permissions is rw for owner and rw for group.

Comment: That's true ... the issue basically remains the same however: the user can not access the device, but root can. Now I can't really see why....

Comment: [Edit] your question to include the output of `id`

Comment: Done! I've added id above